# Plotting the image of a curve under a flow

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I have some explicit time-independent vector field on the plane, and I would like to study how points evolve under the flow generated by this vector field. The flow is rather complicated and cannot be solved explicitly.

For my purposes, it is important to analyze how a "curve" of initial conditions end up after a fixed time, say $t=1$. Is there any command in *Mathematica* that would do this job? I have read much documentation but could not find anything like this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

To be concrete,

```
s = 
  NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == -y[t] + x[t]*Log[x[t]], y'[t] == x[t] + y[t]*Log[x[t]], 
    x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, 
   {x, y}, {t, 1}]
```

and I would like to plot the image of the line segment $1<x<2,\,y=0$ after time 1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y[t] + x[t]*Log[x[t]], 
                            y'[t] ==  x[t] + y[t]*Log[x[t]], 
                            x[0] == x0, y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 1}, x0]
f[x0_, t_] := Through[Through[s@x0]@t]

pts = Table[f[x0, t], {x0, 1, 2, .2}, {t, 0, 1, .1}];
Show[Graphics[{Green, Arrow /@ pts, Black, Point /@ pts}, 
              Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}], 
     ParametricPlot[f[x0, 1], {x0, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
     ParametricPlot[f[x0, 0], {x0, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or.

```
pts = Table[f[x0, t], {x0, 1, 2, .2}, {t, 0, 1, .1}];
ptsind = Transpose[{(Range@Length@# - 1)/(Length@# - 1), #} &@Transpose@pts];

Graphics[
  {Green, Arrow /@ pts,
  {Thick, Blend[{Blue, Red}, #[[1]]], Line@#[[2]]} & /@ ptsind},
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect for my purposes. It will be very useful in my studies.

Answer (score 6):

Make the position along the curve be another parameter of the differential equation.

```
s = NDSolve[{D[x[t, x0], t] == -y[t, x0] + x[t, x0]*Log[x[t, x0]], 
   D[y[t, x0], t] == x[t, x0] + y[t, x0]*Log[x[t, x0]], 
   x[0, x0] == x0, y[0, x0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 1}, {x0, 1, 2}];
ParametricPlot[
 Table[{x[t, x0], y[t, x0]} /. s, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}], {x0, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for; my apologies for not being able to accept multiple answers.